# What areas of a shower are the most prone to moisture & mold?

Tags: shower, grout

This may sound like an obvious question but I am thinking of a specific diagram which I have seen in the past which I cannot locate.

It showed a sort of diagonal division between the wettest areas near the shower head and other areas which tended to stay dry or drier. (I might have seen it in some video, not on its own, which might be why I can't find it again!)

The specific reason I'm looking for this is to help evaluate whether and where to use epoxy grout. I'm building a 3x5 ft. shower and given that the epoxy is harder to work with and more expensive, am trying to decide if I can economize money & effort by using regular grout in secondary areas where there is little benefit to the epoxy.

Thanks

Comment: Sorry, can't resist: You only have to worry about two areas - the inside and the outside.

Comment: Epoxy grout for ceramic tile and stone is not a replacement for a waterproof membrane.

Comment: Where does the water hit the walls? That'd be my guess as to the wettest areas. Depends on the shower head position, spray pattern, where you stand, how the water deflects off your body...........

Comment: @Alaskaman thanks & yes I was planning to Redgard it before tile. But grout mold is stlil a concern.